# Removing all previously loaded ViewControllers from memory iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am currently editing a code previously written, 
In the application, The first viewController is a table view controller named: ListViewController that has several elements, each selection of row creates a new instance of a view controller and presents it modally. but in those view controllers, instead of dismissing them, the previous developer again created the instance of the ListViewController and presents it modally to go back.

The application is obviously using alot of memory.

Dismissing the view controllers is not an option.

if I pop view controllers in the stack one by one, this doesn't work, each view has popups etc presented on viewdidAppear.

I need to remove all previously loaded ViewControllers from memory and present a viewController such that there are no instances of any ViewControllers left in the memory. 
Is it possible? 
Is there a way i can goto say a new ViewController called HomeViewController ensuring that all previously loaded instances of all view controllers are released.

The scenario is as following:

```
                         ListViewController 
                     /            |            \ 
             AViewController  BViewController  CViewController
```

ListViewController has 3 elements

A
B
C

user can tap any of them, that results in presenting a ViewController.
and from each of the view controllers, when back button is pressed, The ListViewController is presented.

Views are presented using the following code:

```
if let listViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListViewController") as? ListViewController {
                    self.presentViewController(listViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
```

Comment: can you not keep a boolean that will mark whether the popup has shown or not in the viewDidAppear? then you can pop and the popups wont trigger. but sounds like the whole thing needs to be refactored

Comment: Why can't you dismiss VCs?

Comment: I agree, each view Controller is using different resources, there is even a SpriteKit game scene in between. Is it not possible to move to a new view controller releasing all previous ones, like the application has just started, no properties or states are required, just a fresh start.

Comment: @Sweeper when I dismiss a VC, The previous one is shown, I mean if ListViewController was presenting them, then dismissing was very simple, but each view controller either presents the ListViewController or any other View Controller. So it can be any possible combination, like ListViewControler -> A -> ListViewController -> B -> C -> A -> ListViewController -> A

Comment: @Hammadzafar It sounds like the back button's implementation is bad. You should just change the back button so that it dismisses/pops the VCs

Comment: @Sweeper its not just the back button, I have already changed the back button implementation to dismiss view Controller but the issue is that there are other ways a new viewcontroller can be presented, if the user lets say from ViewController A taps the OK Button, it goes to the ViewController C. So when I dismiss view controller C, it presents A, and A has implementation in ViewDidAppear,

Comment: One thing you can do is to set ListViewController as your rootViewController everytime you dismiss a viewController. This will ensure that all viewControllers in memory are released

Comment: @ShayanJalil Ok, I'm trying this, should the ListViewController be set as root view controller in app delegate? after setting it to root view controller, should I do something like this : `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: Is it possible to reload the application to the storyboard's entry point?

Comment: @Hammadzafar no you do not have to pop after setting rootViewController. Once you set the rootViewController, all the other existing viewControllers in the view heirarchy are automatically removed. One thing to keep in mind is that every time you set your ListViewController as rootViewController, it would be initialized again

Comment: @Hammadzafar check the edit in answer

Comment: @RajanMaheswari Yes I'm trying your method. I'll update you once I'm done.

Comment: @ShayanJalil I set the ListViewController as Root View Controller. It doesn't automatically pop others so i use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` But It appears that the previous ViewControllers are still in memory as no memory is freed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it will work. Try this. Before presenting any new `ViewController`.

Make a method in `AppDelegate`

```
func switchControllers(viewControllerToBeDismissed:UIViewController,controllerToBePresented:UIViewController) {
        if (viewControllerToBeDismissed.isViewLoaded && (viewControllerToBeDismissed.view.window != nil)) {
            // viewControllerToBeDismissed is visible
            //First dismiss and then load your new presented controller
            viewControllerToBeDismissed.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(controllerToBePresented, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Now lets say you move like this

`ViewController` --> You click a button and present a `SecondViewController`

So currently we have `ViewController` and `SecondViewController` in memory.

Now when you click some button in `SecondViewController` in order to present a `ThirdViewController`, then `SecondViewController` must dismiss. So in `SecondViewController` button Press

```
@IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let controllerToBePresented = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
    appDelegate.switchControllers(viewControllerToBeDismissed: self, controllerToBePresented: controllerToBePresented)
}
```

So now we have `ViewController` and `ThirdViewController` in memory.
`SecondViewController` is removed from memory.

Better solution is to keep your controllers in `UINavigationController` stack because you can get an array of all `ViewControllers` pushed on stack.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but this doesn't work. When I use this code, the if always resolves to true, and it neither dismisses the current view controller nor it presents the new one.

Comment: you have to write the code for dismiss.. I just made in comments..`First dismiss and then load your new presented controller`

Comment: Yes this is what I'm doing, here's the code:

    `if oldVC.isViewLoaded() && oldVC.view.window != nil {
                    
oldVC.dismiss
                    if let AVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("A") as? AViewController {
                        
presentVC(AVC)
                    }
                }
                else {
                   
if let AVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("A") as? AViewController {
                        
presentVC(AVC)
                    }
                    }
                }`

Comment: where are you writing this code? It should be somewhere where the class must exists in memory, like appDelegate. Wait I ll edit

Comment: I have implemented your solution, It works in a few VCs so that means your solution is correct, Quick Question, does dismissing the ViewController like we are, does this free up the memory it was using? because I'm monitoring the memory used, and I don't see any changes from the previous usage.

Comment: Memory management is done by ARC. You have dismissed the VC from memory. Rest garbage collector will do for you. If you really want to check, just take your app to background and bring again to foreground after you dismiss the view controller. Garbage colllector runs by time to time automatically.

Comment: @Hammadzafar if it helps you kindly accept as a tick. Thanks

Comment: Perfect! I just checked and It does clear up some memory when I take the app to background and back. Thanks Sir. this really helped.